# ImportError: No module named kivy (Running in IDLE from Windows Desktop)

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I feel semi-advanced at python now on PC and I feel like trying coding for Android. After searching through some libraries the most suitable i could find was Kivy (The others seemed mainly for python 2.7). After going through Kivy's pip installation page with no errors I tried copying their basic script to check if everything went smoothly, however the code returns an error.

```
import kivy kivy.require('1.9.1') 

from kivy.app import App from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

When running this code through IDLE(Which I assume is incorrect) it returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Python Programs\Kivy Basic\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ImportError: No module named kivy
```

Thanks!

Comment: It seems the Kivy installation was not completed correctly. Re-check the terminal and look for errors there.

Comment: did you set the correct interpreter for your project in the IDE?

Comment: You're probably running python3 while pip was install with python2.. like python -m pip install kivy..instead python3 -m pip install kivy